# How can I set parameters of a transfer function with variable x(1..n) in order to optimize my model in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulink

In order to optimize my Simulink model I need to create an objective function that calculates the difference between the measurements and the response of the model. I tried with this alternative :

```
function f = fun(x)
sim(Model);
set_param(Model/Gain, Gain , x(1));
...
y =yout;
f = mesearments - y;
```

That didn't work well, I found another command, `[y] = lsim(Model, u, t)`, but I would like to know what the `u` and `t` represent.
I followed the [MATLAB documentation][1], but that didn't work with my model, maybe because my model is too complex.

[1]https://mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/lsim.html

Comment: What documentation? Can you share a link? And how didn't it work? Did you computer catch fire when running it?

Answer (score 0):

`lsim` is used to simulate linear systems, so isn't relevant for your case.  If you look at the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/linearizing-models.html?searchHighlight=lsim) then you'll see that the model is a linear system, not a Simulink model.

To address your question about `lsim`, the `u` and the `t` are input and time vector respectively, for the linear simulation.

You haven't told us specifically why your original effort *didn't work well*, but I suspect it's because you are using `set_param` incorrectly.  The new gain value needs to be a string. That is, you need something like

`set_param(Model/Gain, Gain , num2str(x(1)));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PhilGoddard , my nw gain value is already a string. My problem might be caused by the `set_param` of the transfer function, in my case I have: 

`Num = [x(1) x(2)]; 
set_param(Model/tf,Numerator,'Num');`
and the same for the `Denominator` . 
Otherwise my problem might come from the use of `yout` in the objective function that I already mentionned in the question.